How do I determine the exact date and time of an OS upgrade?
I installed an upgrade to OS 14.4.1 and it appears to have caused severe performance degradation. I would like to restore the system from a backup, but I don't know the exact time of the update. I would prefer not to restore multiple versions in order to find the nearest backup with the old OS. Is there a way to figure out exactly when the update was installed through terminal or some other mechanism?

Can I encourage you to ask a separate question to look into the performance issues? If you choose to do so, please include specific examples and relevant screenshots from Activity Monitor.

@nohillside Yes I might, though I am trying to see if downgrading actually fixes the problem.

@nohillside I figured out the issue and some workarounds: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/122394 It is unresolved and an Apple engineer is looking into it. I am experiencing a 10x slowdown in certain GPU operations (something that took 6 seconds is taking 60 seconds). There are some less than ideal work arounds to speed it up while I wait for them to figure it out. Not sure it is worth posting another question since I've identified the issue. Also if I need to downgrade, 14.3.1 looks good enough (though I think I am just going to wait since it is being looked into)

Assume people impacted by the issue will find it on GitHub anyway.

These are tracked.
Look in System Information >> Software >> Installations.


Great thanks! Accepted. It appears I cannot actually go back to the old OS using just time machine, but that is a separate issue that I will ask about in a different question.

Here's a programmatic method for use in a Terminal. It relies on jq being installed to parse the JSON output (a common utility that can be installed with brew install jq):
system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType -json |
jq -r --arg v $(sw_vers --productVersion) '
.SPInstallHistoryDataType |
map(select(._name|test("^macOS \($v)")))[-1] |
.install_date |
strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") |
strftime("%a %Y-%m-%d %-I:%M:%S %p")'

Example output on my 14.4.1 system:
Mon 2024-03-25 6:57:07 PM

If you don't need to reformat the ISO8601 date provided by system_profiler, you can remove the strptime and strftime commands at the tail end of the jq program to shorten it. Example output:
2024-03-25T18:57:07Z

